# starting minidfscluster in tests

Tags: java, testing, hadoop, junit, classloader

I'm starting MiniDfsCluster (my dependencies are 2.0.0-cdh4.5.0) in my test. I use a simple routine to start it:

```
File baseDir = new File("./target/hdfs/" + RunWithHadoopCluster.class.getSimpleName()).getAbsoluteFile();
FileUtil.fullyDelete(baseDir);
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
MiniDFSCluster.Builder builder = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf);
MiniDFSCluster hdfsCluster = builder.build();
String hdfsURI = "hdfs://localhost:"+ hdfsCluster.getNameNodePort() + "/";
```

and keep getting the following error.

```
12:02:15.994 [main] WARN  o.a.h.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig - Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-namenode.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
12:02:16.047 [main] INFO  o.a.h.m.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
12:02:16.047 [main] INFO  o.a.h.m.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - NameNode metrics system started

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.source.JvmMetrics.getEventCounters(JvmMetrics.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.source.JvmMetrics.getMetrics(JvmMetrics.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMetrics(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.updateJmxCache(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMBeanInfo(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:150)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getNewMBeanClassName(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:333)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:319)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.register(MBeans.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.startMBeans(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.start(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.registerSource(MetricsSystemImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.source.JvmMetrics.create(JvmMetrics.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.metrics.NameNodeMetrics.create(NameNodeMetrics.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initMetrics(NameNode.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:613)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNode(MiniDFSCluster.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNodesAndSetConf(MiniDFSCluster.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster$Builder.build(MiniDFSCluster.java:305)
```

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your dependencies. This error indicates there are incompatible versions of logging jars on the classpath. I faced a similar problem and had to exclude the log4j-over-slf4j dependency which was introduced by another third-party library.

Comment: That's right! When I remove log4j dependencies there is no such error.

Comment: Actually I was better off, excluding log4j-over-slf4j bridge from storm-core :) Just as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to SLF4J 1.7.6 should solve the issue (we used 1.7.7 though) as the log4j-over-slf4j v1.7.5 is missing AppenderSkeleton.

Quite likely a class is using Log4J somewhere which is invoking AppenderSkeleton, but then the bridge to redirect log4j through slf4j is missing that, and it blows up with the stack trace the poster shows.  The release notes on http://www.slf4j.org/news.html describe that this was addressed in 1.7.6.

Logged on Yarn, where we saw the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2875.